# How to show multi-variable function is onto?

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

Given $f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x,y)=x−y$, how can I show that the function is onto?

If it were a single variable function I'd prove that there is an inverse function hence it has to be onto, but I never dealt with multi-variable functions so I don't know how.

Comment: Can you find $x,y$ such that $x-y=k$?

Comment: You need to show that each element in $R$ can be represented by an element in $R \times R$ with the given function. For example $x - y$ with $y = 0$ seems like a reasonable try.

Comment: You can give a (right) inverse function alright, it's $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, defined by $g(z)=(z,0)$. Easy to check that $f\circ g = \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: Be careful. There is no inverse function for surjective maps, only a right-inverse. The distinction 'multi-variable or not' is an artificial one, and only distracting you from what matters here. kingW3 gave the best hint here....

Comment: Fix $y=0$ the resulting function $x \mapsto x-0$ is onto. Hence $f$ is onto.

Comment: Yeah showing that x-y=k exists makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $f(x,0) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=x-y$ is onto. Given any $r \in \mathbb{R}$, take $x=r$ and $y=0$. Then, $f(x,y)=f(r,0)=r-0=r$.  Hence, every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is the image of some point $(r,0) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. This proves that $f$ is surjective.