# Is the multivariate function $G:\mathbb{Q} $ x $ \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $G(x, y) = r + \sqrt 2 * s$ onto, one-to-one, or both?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I recently had a quiz in which I was given the following question:

> Define a function $G:\mathbb{Q} $ x $ \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $G(x, y) = r + \sqrt 2 s$. Is G onto, one-to-one, or both?

I was not able to solve whether or not G was either onto or one-to-one when writing. I tried the following proof, but could not get further than this:

> Let $r_1, r_2, s_1, s_2\in \mathbb{Q} $ x $ \mathbb{Q}$ such that $G(r_1, s_2) = G(r_2, s_2)$. That is, that $r_1 + \sqrt 2 s_1 = r_2 + \sqrt 2 s_2$.
>
> Then,
> $$\sqrt 2 s_1 - \sqrt 2 s_2 = r_2 - r_1$$
> $$\Rightarrow \sqrt 2 (s_1 - s_2) = r_2 - r_1$$

I wanted to set $s_1, s_2$ equal to something that would produce a non-zero integer on the LHS, but I could not find a pair of integers that would do this.

We were given the following theorem to take for granted:

> $\mathbf {Theorem}$: If $n$ is an integer that is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt n$ is irrational.

In trying to prove that G is not onto, I tried setting $r+\sqrt 2 s=\sqrt 47$, then tried to show that since $r,s\in\mathbb Q, G(r, s) \neq \sqrt 47$ for any $r, s\in \mathbb Q$. But I've had no luck with this method, and so I don't know what the correct way to prove this is. There are some other questions on math.stackexchange such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255219/how-to-show-multi-variable-function-is-onto), but the $\sqrt 2$ is preventing me from using the proofs given in the answers of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have $\sqrt 2 (s_1 - s_2) = r_2 - r_1$. If $s_1=s_2$, then you have$r_1+\sqrt 2s_1=r_2+\sqrt 2s_2\implies r_1=r_2$ and $G $ is one-one. If $s_1\neq s_2$, then $\sqrt 2=\dfrac{r_2 - r_1}{s_1 - s_2}\in \Bbb Q,$ a contradiction(remember $\Bbb Q$ is field).

**Claim**: $G $ is not onto.

Suppose there exist  $a,b\in \Bbb Q$ such that  $\sqrt3=a+b\sqrt2. $ Squaring, we get $3=a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt2$. If $ab\neq 0$, then $\sqrt2=\dfrac {3-(a^2+2b^2)}{2ab}\in \Bbb Q$, a contradiction. So  $ab=0$.

Suppose  $a=0$. Then $\sqrt3=b\sqrt2$ or $\sqrt{6}=2b\in \Bbb Q$, again a contradiction.

So $b=0$. But that would imply $\sqrt3=a\in \Bbb Q,\rightarrow\leftarrow$.

Hence $G $ is not onto.

---

If you know some real analysis stuff, you can see that $\Bbb Q×\Bbb Q $ is countably infinite whereas  $\Bbb R $ is uncountably infinite. Now if $G $ is onto, then $G $ would be a bijection. But we can't have a bijection from a countable set to an uncountable set. So $G $ is not onto.

Comment: Might want to add that the domain is countable but the codomain is not, so surjectivity cannot hold for that reason as well!

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you. I've edited my answer. I was concentrating on the theorem OP gave.

Comment: You are welcome! (+1)

Comment: Thank you. I understand the proof that $G$ is not onto, but I'm a little hazy with multivariate functions. You show that if $s_1 = s_2$ then $G$ is one-to-one, but if $s_1 \neq s_2$ then $G$ is not one-to-one. Does this show that G is one-to-one only in the former case, or is $G$ never one-to-one?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now that $s_1 = s_2$ has to be true as if it wasn't then we'd be able to produce a contradiction.